# Import registry where registry is disabled by GPO

Tags: windows, vbscript, registry

I am currently trying to import a registry file in a logon script that uses VBScript.  However a group of users have registry/cmd disabled through the group policy (unchangeable due to policy). The code works for users that have registry/cmd access just not for the rest.

```
Dim wsh
Set wsh = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wsh.Run "%SystemRoot%\regedit.exe /S \\LogonServer\LogonFiles\reg\languages.reg", , True
```

Comment: Use `WshShell.RegWrite()` to write the values individually. (See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfdfhz1b(v=vs.84).aspx), http://ss64.com/vb/regwrite.html)

Comment: Or use [Group Policy Preferences](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn581922.aspx). Importing .reg files requires registry tools enabled.

Comment: Incidentally, if policy prohibits certain users from using the registry editor or the command line interpreter, you should also be prohibiting them from using vbscript, for the sake of consistency if nothing else.  Anything malicious they could do with cmd and regedit could just as easily be done with vbscript!